# How to configure Test Outcomes in TestPlans in Azure Devops

Tags: testing, azure-devops

I'm new to using TestPlans in Azure DevOps and need a couple more Test Outcomes than the standard ones provided.  How do I configure the available Test Outcomes.  I need to add 'Queried', 'Concession' and 'ReTest'.

In our current Test Management software we use 'Queried' for where someone has expressed the test incorrectly (since this isn't a fail), 'Concession' for allowing failures into a release and 'ReTest' to signal that a defect has been fixed.

How do I manage this in TestPlans in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, we cannot customize the Test Outcomes in Azure DevOps. We can only use the existing ones (passed, failed, blocked or not applicable). Please refer to [New Test Plans page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/new-test-plans-page?view=azure-devops) for details.

However, you can try to tag the test cases. Please refer to [Q: Can I tag test cases so that I can see only tests with specific tags?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/reference-qa?view=azure-devops#q-can-i-tag-test-cases-so-that-i-can-see-only-tests-with-specific-tags) for details.

Comment: @SuW Any update to this ticket? is the answer helpful for you?